# Sequence Action only first action is working in LIBGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, action, scene2d

I am trying to add a sequence action. The problem is that only the first added action taken effect. For example in below code if i add mta first, I can only see mta action (the second action doesn't work). If I reverse then I see only the mtabite take effect. 
Please help

```
MoveToAction mta = new MoveToAction();
mta.setPosition(x, y);
mta.setDuration(4f);

MoveToAction mtaBite = new MoveToAction();
mtaBite.setPosition(xFinal, yFinal);
mtaBite.setDuration(4f);

SequenceAction sequence = new SequenceAction();
sequence.addAction(mta);
sequence.addAction(mtaBite);

this.addAction(sequence);
```

Comment: working both action in sequence, make sure `x, y` coordinate is different form  `xFinal, yFinal`, otherwise you don't see action transition.

Comment: It's better to use pooled `Action` so use `addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveTo(x,y,4f),Actions.moveTo(xFinal, yFinal,4f)));`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. The problem is elsewhere. Maybe show more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead see if it works better:

```
actor.addAction(Actions.sequence(mta, mtaBite));
```

Also make sure your Actions are setup correctly.

```
mta.reset();
mta.setTime(0);
mta.setPosition(x, y);
mta.setInterpolation(Interpolation.fade);
mta.setDuration(4f);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is best to use Tween Engine in order to animate in he libgdx.

Tween.to(myobject, Type.POSITION, 1.0f)
    .targetRelative(10, -20)  // the target can be relative to the current values
    .delay(2.5f)              // a delay can be specified
    .ease(Quad.OUT)           // the easing function can be modified
    .repeat(2, 0.5f)          // repetitions are possible
    .repeatYoyo(2, 0.5f)      // yoyo repetitions too (one play forward, the other backward, etc)
    .setUserData(obj)         // custom objects can be attached
    .setCallback(cb)          // callbacks can be specified to get notified of the completion
    .setCallbackTriggers(...) // callbacks can be launched on many events, not just completion
    .start(myManager);

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/

Comment: can you explain why `universal-tween-engine` is better option in compare with inbuilt `Actions` for scene-2d graph in libgdx.

Comment: Please try to answer the question, not force-feed other technologies.